# Flex 4.6 - Event Handling Conflict

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, event-handling, flex4

I have a datagrid with many columns and one of the columns contains a set of buttons using ItemRenderer. The datagrid itself has a clicked event which displays a panel. However, when any of the buttons is clicked, the clicked event of the datagrid should not be executed. How can I achieve this? Currently both the button click and datagrid events are being dispatched when the buttons are clicked.

Below is the current implementation:

---

**Monitoring.mxml** which has a **datagrid** and one of the column uses **ItemRenderer** to store a set a buttons.

```
<s:GridColumn width="300" dataField="" headerText="Control Buttons"
                          itemRenderer="com.example.ItemRenderer.ButtonControlsItemRenderer">
</s:GridColumn>
```

Inside the **ButtonControlsItemRenderer.mxml**, I have 2 buttons - Log and Advisory

```
<s:Button id="btn_log" width="49" height="35" label="Log" 
              click="btn_log_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:Button id="btn_Advisory" width="81" height="35" label="Advisory"
              click="btn_Advisory_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

and these 2 buttons are dispatching custom events to the datagrid with these functions.

```
protected function btn_log_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var myEventObject:Event = new Event("logButtonEventRenderer",true);
            dispatchEvent(myEventObject);
}

protected function btn_Advisory_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            var myEventObject1:Event = new Event("AdvisoryButtonEventRenderer",true);
            dispatchEvent(myEventObject1);  
}
```

Event metadata have been declared and event listeners have been added in **Monitoring.mxml**:

```
[Event(name="logButtonEvent", type="com.example.GetSelectedSystemEvent")]
[Event(name="AdvisoryButtonEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]

dg_Events.addEventListener("logButtonEventRenderer",btn_logButtonHandler); 
dg_Events.addEventListener("AdvisoryButtonEventRenderer",btn_AdvisoryButtonHandler);

protected function btn_logButtonHandler(event:Event):void{
    // Do something; 
}

protected function btn_AdvisoryButtonHandler(event:Event):void{
    // Do something
}

//Datagrid Click Event
protected function dg_Events_gridClickHandler(event:GridEvent):void { 
    // Display Panel
}
```

Thank you and really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call stopImmediatePropagation function in the button click hanler.Mouse event will bubble.

```
protected function btn_log_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
   var myEventObject:Event = new Event("logButtonEventRenderer",true);
   dispatchEvent(myEventObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried that but the datagrid's clicked event still triggered. I only need the button clicked event to be dispatched.

Comment: Have you add stopImmediatePropagation in both btn_logButtonHandler and btn_AdvisoryButtonHandler?

Comment: Yup but it doesn't work still. I print the eventPhase and eventCurrentTarget and it seemed that the datagrid's clicked event is being executed first.

Comment: I think the reason using `stopImmediatePropagation()` doesn't work here is because we're talking about two different event types. Look at the types of events used in each handler: `MouseEvent` and `GridEvent`. You can't stop propagation of a different event. @Gzzzy have you tried listening for a regular `MouseEvent.CLICK` on the grid? There may be issues w/that, because they took the trouble to create a separate `GridEvent` type. You could also try using the `columnIndex` or `column` properties of the `GridEvent` to know when the user is clicking on your magic buttons.

Comment: I just found same reason. At first I thought it's mouseEvent added on the datagrid. So try to use MouseEvent instead of GridEvent .

Comment: I used the columnIndex method and it works! Thanks @SunilD. and Pan for your kind replies. Have a nice day =)

Comment: @SunilD. is right. But it does use MouseEvent under the hood to create the GridEvent if I recall well; but it's MOUSE_DOWN or MOUSE_UP (don't remember which one). Try stopping the propagation of one of those.